# Converting a buffer of multiple C-strings into a vector of strings

Tags: c++, istream, std, istream-iterator

Win32 API's GetLogicalDriveStrings returns a buffer of C-strings which looks something like:
`"C:\<NULL>D:\<NULL>E:\<NULL><NULL>"`. I wanted to return a vector of strings and thought about using an istream iterator:

```
std::vector< std::string > foo()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer( new char[1024+1] );
    buffer[1024] = '\0';

    const auto length = GetLogicalDriveStrings( 1024, buffer.get() );
    std::istringstream ss( std::string( buffer.get(), buffer.get()+length ) );

    return std::vector< std::string >(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>( ss ),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
    );
}
```

How ever this always returns a vector of size 1. I suppose istream_iterator considers its job done when he finds a null byte.  Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: I've tried to reduce your problem to a [program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff871e9d9a8bb642) that doesn't require the Windows API. Can you confirm this is the problem you're experiencing?